# Time series data analysis - determining significance between treatment and control

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

We have some time series data for evaluating the effect of a drug in an animal model, with two dose levels and a control. So far we've looked at ANOVA for each time point, and there's a significant effect for the middle time points. However, the drug dose is not constant, as it needed to be reduced at later time points, which caused a convergence in the treatment and control by the end, so at the final time point the effect is not significant with ANOVA. What other approaches might we take with analyzing this data aside from the basic ANOVA? We aren't interested in prediction, just in evaluating significance at this time.

Comment: why did the dose need to be reduced? if it was reduced based on data from prior time points, this is obviously an issue that isn't easily addressed

Answer (score 1):

> However, the drug dose is not constant, as it needed to be reduced at
>   later time points, which caused a convergence in the treatment and
>   control by the end

First, this is an assumption you are making. I would recommend treating the control as 0 dose and fitting a dose response curve at each time point. Then we could attempt to determine whether the parameters of the curve change over time. However, with three datapoints per timepoint this may not be reasonable.

It would be best if there was previous literature with dose-response curves or a theoretical curve that you could compare your results to (the previous dose response curve would be your "null hypothesis"). Can provide additional information and the data (or similar data)?